# Drawing a tangent from a point outside of a circle to it!

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I have an easy question. I want to draw the tangents from origin to a circle with center at e.g. (0,2) and radius 1.5. Here the code of the circle:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (3,-.5) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\draw (0,2) circle (1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I need a simple solution, because I'm not good at drawing with `tikz`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Tangent coordinate system

TikZ knows a tangent coordinate system for shapes, if library `calc` is loaded,
see section "13.2.4 Tangent Coordinate Systems" of the PGF/TikZ manual.

The circle is drawn as node with circular shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (3,-.5) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
% \draw (0,2) circle (1.5);
\node[circle, draw] (c) at (0, 2) [minimum size=3cm] {};
\draw[red]
  (0, 0) coordinate (a)
  -- (tangent cs:node=c, point={(a)}, solution=1)
  (0, 0)
  -- (tangent cs:node=c, point={(a)}, solution=2)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Trigonometry

The angle and length of the lines can be calculated using the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) and the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (3,-.5) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\draw (0,2) circle (1.5);
\pgfmathsetmacro\angle{asin(1.5/2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\len{sqrt(2*2 - 1.5*1.5)}
\draw[red]
  (0, 0) -- (90 - \angle:\len)
  (0, 0) -- (90 + \angle:\len)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Intersections

The question from the comment can be solved with library `intersections`.
A line is defined, which goes through the circle. Then the intersections are calculated and the line drawn:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (3,-.5) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[name path=circle] (0,2) coordinate (center) circle (1.5);
\coordinate (arbitrary point) at ($(center) + (-80:1.5)$);
% PGF/TikZ manual: 13.5.4 The Syntax of Distance Modifiers
\path[name path=line] (0, 0) -- ($(arbitrary point)!3cm!180:(0, 0)$);
\draw[red, name intersections={of=circle and line}]
  (0, 0) -- (intersection-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I draw a line from origin intersecting the circle at arbitrary point and ending on circle?

Comment: @Immanuel See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly tikz but here it's tkz-euclide. Tikz is my favorite tool to draw geometry's figures but I built tkz-euclide for math teachers to achieve results with a tool and a syntax similar to Latex. Euclide is based over tikz and you can use options and commands from tikz.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=-0.5,ymax=3]
             % axis defined by Init
        \tkzDrawX[noticks] \tkzDrawY[noticks]
             % it's fine to use points with names
             % rule if you use an object, you use parenthesis
             %      if you want to get an object, you use  curly braces
        \tkzDefPoints{0/2/A,0/0/O}
        \tkzDrawCircle[R](A,1.5 cm) % option R I use a radius
                                    % with \tkzDefPoint(1.5,2){C} 
                                    % \tkzDrawCircle(A,C)
        \tkzTangent[from with R=O](A,1.5 cm)  \tkzGetPoints{a}{b}
              % or \tkzTangent[from O](A,C)
        \tkzDrawSegments[color=green!50!black](O,a O,b A,a)
        \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,a,O)
              %  possible get a random point on the circle
              %  \tkzGetRandPointOn[circle=center A radius 1.5cm]{M}
              %  \tkzDrawSegment[color=red](O,M)
        \tkzDefPoint(1,4){B}
        \tkzInterLC[R](O,B)(A,1.5cm) \tkzGetPoints{x}{y}
              % or \tkzInterLC(O,B)(A,C)
        \tkzDrawSegment[color=red](O,x)
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for tkz-euclid. If possible, please consider providing English documentation.

Comment: @Dilawar I’ m not certain to write a full doc but a little one yes !

Answer (score 0):

I think tkz-euclide is a great tool, however it is still unstable which is problematic if you write some code and then reuse it a few years later. The answer has to  be modulated depending which version you are using:

- for version 1.16 (answer given): `\tkzTangent[from ...]`
- for version 3.06:                `\tkzDefTangent[from = ...]`
- for version 4.2:                 `\tkzDefLine[tangent from = ...]`

The problem is to know exactly which version you are using if you use a Latex package linked either to Overleaf or a Linux distribution (in my case Mint).

- My Latex package is updated by the distribution, it is very convenient but it is not always the latest version. Moreover Mint is Debian based, so installing and updating the *TexLive.Iso* is not easy, even discouraged.
- You may get a wrong drawing without any diagnostic! Just check the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
 \begin{document} 
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} .
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-5,-4.5) rectangle (8.5,4);
\def \Xa{0}
\def \Ya{0}
\def \Xid{2*sqrt(3) + 2*sqrt(2)}
\def \Yid{2}
\def \rd{2}
\def \Xtab{2*sqrt(3) + 2*sqrt(2)}
\def \Ytab{0}
\def \Xtbc{2*sqrt(2) + 8*sqrt(3)/3}
\def \Ytbc{2*sqrt(6)/3 + 2}
\def \Xap{-2*sqrt(3) - 2*sqrt(2)}
\def \Yap{-sqrt(6) - 2}
\coordinate (Ap) at ({\Xap},{\Yap});
\coordinate (A) at ({\Xa},{\Ya});
\coordinate (I) at ({ \Xid },{\Yid });
\coordinate (K) at ({ \Xtbc },{ \Ytbc });
\coordinate (M) at ({ \Xtab },{\Ytab });
\tkzDrawCircle[blue](I,K);
%%% from manual tkz-euclide tool for Euclidean Geometry V3.06c p94
\tkzDefTangent[from = Ap](I,M) \tkzGetPoints{R}{Q};
\tkzDrawSegment[green](Ap,R);
%%% from manual tkz-euclide Euclidean Geometry V4.2c p43
\tkzDefLine[tangent from = Ap](I,M) \tkzGetPoints{Rp}{Qp}
\tkzDrawSegment[red](Ap,Rp);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You will get a perfect compilation and the following result, no warnings!
[image: Tangent to a circle from a given point]

In my case the version 3.06 gives a correct result, not the most up to date version 4.2...